# Ubuntu 16.04 cannot recognize all my ram

Tags: uefi, ram

Installed 2x4GB ram (DDR3 1600) but the memTotal is only 6.4GB according to

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

`lspci` tells that intel HD 4000 uses 256MB

`dmesg` shows only 6.4GB was recognized when kernel booted.

My kernel is 4.4.32, 64bit + UEFI

Found no video memory config in lenovo k29 laptop's BIOS.

I tried to remove either one of my rams but each time only 2.9GB of 4GB can be recognized. Now although I have 8GB in total but only 6.4 is recognized in Ubuntu 16.04 and only about 4GB available.

Does anyone know what happened to my RAM? Any help is appreciated.